# OSX how to show apache status in terminal?

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx

I noticed that on my linux server when i type apachectl restart it gives me little but helpful feedback such as `restarting` and then `[ok]` or `[fail]` at the end of the line. Not much, but at least I know what is going on, and I can go check logs.

On my OS X i get nothing. just the next line immediately:

```
sh-3.2# /usr/sbin/apachectl stop   
sh-3.2# /usr/sbin/apachectl start
sh-3.2#
```

How can I enable those 'debug' features?

Comment: I'm not familiar with OS X, but you can edit the init script to add an `echo` line.

Comment: where is that script? and what line should i add `echo` to? Sorry, i am new around and need details :\

Comment: I'm not an OS X guy, but perhaps it just follows the Unix philosophy of "no news is good news", and starts to nag you only if there's something wrong?

Comment: hmm silent errors don't help, so i am not a fan really

Comment: Please post the content of `/usr/sbin/apachectl`.

Comment: @quanta: That doesn't matter, `apachectl` has everything in place to exit with an error, but that doesn't work as `launchctl` always exits with `0`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about in the apachectl wrapper script you stick something like this at the end.

```
tail -5 /var/log/httpd/error_log
```

you should see something like this in a normal startup

- [Fri Apr 22 23:39:20 2011] [notice] Digest: generating secret for
  digest authentication ...
- [Fri Apr 22 23:39:20 2011] [notice]    Digest: done
- [Fri Apr 22 23:39:20 2011] [warn] pid file
  /mlk/apache/pid/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous
  Apache run?
- [Fri Apr 22 23:39:20 2011] [notice] Apache/2.0.63 (Unix)    DAV/2
  configured -- **resuming normal operations**

Otherwise any error should at least in part be shown here. The key phrase is hilighted above.

Additional:
/usr/sbin/apachectl is owned by root, you must be a privileged user to do this.
sudo vi /usr/sbin/apachectl

move to the end of the file and insert this between the "esac" and "exit $ERROR" lines.
ie.

```
esac
sleep 2; tail -5 /var/log/httpd/error_log
exit $ERROR
```

Note this will print out the last few lines no matter what action you take with the script, stop start, restart. you may want to only put it in the start part of the case statement.

Comment: That sounds like a possible solution. And how could I attach it so that it automatically executes with each restart command?

Comment: Had to ssh into my macos server at home to look at /usr/bin/apachectl  Look in the answer above i've added the commands to edit the file.

Answer (score 36):

I have the same problem on my mac.  When ever I attempt to start apache and nothing happens, I immediately run this command.  In my case the problem always seems to be in the apache configuration files.

```
apachectl configtest
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I was running into this issue myself, and turns out that an update to homebrew SQLite was causing homebrew PHP to kick up an Apache error that didn't show up anywhere except in configtest.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you!!! This has just saved my sanity!!!

Comment: short version of this command is `apachectl -t`

Comment: This command will tell you if the Apache httpd configuration (httpd.conf) is free of syntax errors. To see if the process is running, you could run "htop" and then F4 to filter on "httpd" to see all of the processes spawned by httpd.

Answer (score 10):

`apachectl` on the Mac is a wrapper around some `launchctl` commands (just look into the file). Unfortunately, launchctl doesn't exit with an error code when something goes wrong with starting `httpd`, so the script has no easy way to display anything, even if it tries to.

A basic check you can perform yourself is to check the existence of Apache processes after the  `apachectl start` command.

```
ps aux | grep httpd
```

Comment: in a way, you are saying, "there is no such debug info you can set on macosx, but this is how you can check if the apache server is running" is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's about it.

Answer (score 0):

On macOS with `netstat` command display all the network connection. You can filter only 'listen' connections and see the http(s) servers.

You can create a bash file with this code:

```
status="$(netstat -at | grep LISTEN | grep *.http)"
count="$(echo "${status}" | grep -Ev "^$" | wc -l)"

if [ ${count} -eq 0 ] ; then
    echo " Apache server is not running"
fi   

echo "${status}" | 
while IFS= read -r line
do
    echo " ${line}"
done
```

Result when server is stoped `sudo apachectl -k stop` will be:

```
Apache server is not running
```

Result when server is running `sudo apachectl -k stop` will be:

```
tcp46      0      0  *.https                *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp46      0      0  *.http                 *.*                    LISTEN
```

In this example I have two servers running, one with https and another with http.